# Average across rows in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table

```
Data   Data1  Data2  YTD
-------------------------
1       2      3      
2       3      4     
3       3      6
```

In the `YTD` column I have to average the rows data. I can use average in columns but not sure how to average across rows.

Looking for the below results and using SQL Server 2008

```
 Data   Data1  Data2  YTD
 ---------------------------------
    1       2      3   2 (Average)   
    2       3      4   3 
    3    null      6   4.5
```

Comment: Constructive feedback: I downvoted this for (a) persistently adding chatty material and please-halp-me pleading despite this being removed from your prior posts, and (b) not making an effort to try some code before asking a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `cross apply` is the simplest method:

```
select t.*, v.avg_data
from t cross apply
     (select avg(v.data) as avg_data
      from (values (t.data), (t.data1), (t.data2)) v(data)
     ) v;
```

Use `case` expressions, you can also express this as:

```
select t.*,
       ( (coalesce(t.data, 0) + (t.data1, 0) + coalesce(t.data2, 0)) /
         nullif( (case when t.data is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
                 (case when t.dat1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
                 (case when t.dat2 is not null then 1 else 0 end), 0
               )
       ) as avg_data;
```

However, this formulation is messy and prone to typing errors.

Comment: Lol Gordon to the rescue..Dude when do you work...seems like you are always just helping others.

Comment: @user1221989 . . . I'm writing a document.  It gives me ample opportunity to pause to think.

Comment: Gordon instead of getting it as a select statement how can I update the main table YTD column with the average values.

Comment: @user1221989 . . . That is a different question and should be asked as a new question.